# Difference between Dynamic Code Analysis and Penetration Testing?

Tags: java, dynamic, analysis, penetration-testing

What, if any, are the differences between Dynamic Code Analysis and Penetration Testing? Are they related?

Comment: Yes, there are many differences, considering pen-testing involves far more than code analysis (and sometimes does not involve *any* code analysis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two concepts which barely have any relation at all.

Dynamic Code Analysis is the observation of a program while it is being executed to gain insight into the program and see what it does and how it does it.

Penetration Testing is an attempt to try out common exploits and hacking techniques on a system by or with permission of the owner. The intention is to detect security flaws so they can be fixed. Penetration testing does not necessarily focus on software. A good penetration test should cover all components of a system. This includes hardware, operating system, software and also the vulnerability of any human components to social engineering attempts.